# How to change Gurobi default python version 2.7.8 to my already installed Python version 3.5 Windows64 (in Spyder)

Tags: python-3.5, gurobi, windows64

I know that there are many posts on how to change your default Python version but none refer to Gurobi recognizing the correct version.

When I open Spyder, Python 3.5 is my default.
How do I get my Gurobi 6.5.2 win64 (which now supports Python 3.5 on Windows64, see [link](http://www.gurobi.com/downloads/get-anaconda)),
to recognize my Python 3.5 as default and not Python 2.7.8?

Answer (score 0):

Judging from [this tutorial](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/6.5/quickstart_mac/the_gurobi_python_interfac.html), you need to point `pysetup` to the location of your Python installation, i.e., the Python 3.5 folder you want.